# Exception trying to open an excel file from Assets folder

Tags: android, excel

This code throws an error but the code is so simple I cannot understand what is wrong (I'm not sure what error is - it just causes the android device to close saying it has unexpectedly had to shut down)

```
public static void load(Context context){

    InputStream is;
    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    try {
        is = am.open("lake1ex.xls");
        Workbook w= Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error Log :

```
 02-21 12:39:46.358: W/ActivityNative(20745): send
 ACTIVITY_IDLE_TRANSACTION 02-21 12:39:50.748: W/dalvikvm(20745): VFY:
 unable to resolve static method 5434: Ljxl/Workbook;.getWorkbook
 (Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljxl/Workbook; 02-21 12:39:50.748:
 W/dalvikvm(20745): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 859
 (Ljxl/read/biff/BiffException;) 02-21 12:39:50.748: W/dalvikvm(20745):
 VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x13 02-21 12:39:50.748:
 W/dalvikvm(20745): VFY: rejected Lcom/example/dcarp/LoadLake;.load
 (Landroid/content/Context;)V 02-21 12:39:50.748: W/dalvikvm(20745):
 VFY: rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0013 02-21 12:39:50.748:
 W/dalvikvm(20745): VFY: rejected Lcom/example/dcarp/LoadLake;.load
 (Landroid/content/Context;)V 02-21 12:39:50.748: W/dalvikvm(20745):
 Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/dcarp/LoadLake;
```

Comment: What is the exact stack trace?

Comment: It's an open GL App. Nothing is displayed on the screen about the stack.

Comment: If u are using Eclipse, go to your logcat (Window->Show View->logcat). If there is an exception, the stacktrace will be printed out. Thats needed here :).

Comment: I cant seem to copy and past it here - but the first error is "Unable to resolve static method 5434: Ljxl/workbook;.getworkbook

Comment: "I cant seem to copy and past it here" -- highlight the lines and press Ctrl-C (or whatever the OS X equivalent is). Also, please indicate how you added your Excel JAR to your project.

Comment: I cannot highlight the lines - sorry! I copied the JAR to the SDK folder and added it to the build path (before I did that I got an unresolved error on the workbook object.

Comment: Ahh - got the copy to work!

Comment: I've added the LogCat below my original question. Thanks for your time.